# Drawing Basic Shapes in WPF InkCanvas

Tags: wpf, silverlight, drawing, inkcanvas

I am working on a  paint like application in wpf.I want the users to be able to add some drawings over images or plain surfaces.Also i want to draw some basic shapes like line,ellipse or a rectangle.I am trying to work with an inkcanvas,where i can do freehand drawing,but i cant draw shapes like in paint.Can anyone guide me and provide some clues on how to do it.Please help me on this.Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anybody..?


I tried a few samples but cant get to do what i am looking for.I want to draw a circle or a rectangle like in mspaint.I want to mark some parts of an image and save the output as image.Thats why i thought of using inkcanvas.But cant get my way through.Please lead me.

Answer (score 3):

There are two sorts of collections in an InkCanvas:

Strokes, which are composed of StylusPoints and defined by DrawingAttributes.  That's what the Ink is, as drawn by a mouse or stylus.

The other is Children, which can contain FrameworkElements.  Ellipse, for instance, is a Shape is a FrameworkElement.

Try playing around with yourCanvas.Children.Add(ellipse) and see how you go.  There is certainly no reason to shy away from the InkCanvas just because you also want to use predefined shapes.

It's worth pointing out, though, that the InkCanvas's little brother, the InkPresenter, does NOT have a Children property.  And Silverlight only has that one.

Comment: Silverlight InkPresenter has a Children property.  I am wondering perhaps it did not in an earlier version?

Answer (score 0):

WPF provides a Shape class that includes prebuilt methods that you can draw shapes with. Don't use the inkcanvas and instead draw directly to a canvas.

Comment: hmm..i chose inkcanvas because it provides inbuilt functionality for saving strokes

Comment: However, it is less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Here http://ciintelligence.blogspot.com/2011/07/silverlight-drawing-tool-silver-draw.html
you can find better control which improved SilverDraw control with extra features:

Freatures are:
* You can draw basic shapes and also can draw using freehand pencil.
* You can erase drawing.
* You can undo and redo drawing.
* Can save drawing as jpeg in server side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation:

```
public void drawCircleAp(Double EHeight, Double EWidth, InkCanvas surface)
{
  Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse();
  e1.Width = EWidth;
  e1.Height = EHeight;
  var brush = new SolidColorBrush();
  brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 0);
  e1.Stroke = brush;
  e1.StrokeThickness = 4;
  surface.Children.Add(e1);
}
```